# How to sum values depending on another column, substract Aliases

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, pivot

SQL-Noob here.

Having a bunch of items which are either bought or sold.

[image]

I would like to Group by item-name and get a sum of purchases and sales.
Also i would like to calculate the stock of items.

I tried a subquery:

```
SELECT NAME,
(
    SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM transactions
    WHERE `type` = "Buy") AS "purchases",
(
    SELECT SUM(quantity)
    FROM transactions
    WHERE `type` = "Sell") AS "sales"
FROM transactions
GROUP BY NAME
```

which results in wrong values:

[image]

After that i tried CASE-Statements

```
SELECT NAME,
SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = "Buy" THEN quantity END) AS "purchases",
SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = "Sell" THEN quantity END) AS "sales"
FROM transactions
GROUP BY name
```

which works:

[image]

**Question 1: Is there a better way to achieve the result?**

**Question 2: How to calculate the Stock of the items?**

Something like `purchases - sales AS "Stock"` doesn't seem to work.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
    sum(case when type = 'Buy'  then quantity else 0 end) as purchases,
    sum(case when type = 'Sell' then quantity else 0 end) as sales,
    sum(case when type = 'Buy'  then quantity else - quantity end) as stock
from transactions
where type in ('Buy', 'Sell')
group by name
```

The `where` clause is not necessary of there are just those types in the table.

Side notes:

- using single quotes for literal strings rather than double quotes; this is standard SQL, that all databases understand
- in MySQL, use backticks if you need to quote an identifier rather than double quotes; or better yet, use identifiers that do not require quoting

Comment: There is a comma missing in second line, can't edit it mysqlf due to rep.